# Ruby daemons and JRuby - alternative options

Tags: ruby, jruby, fork

I have an app that I am migrating from Ruby to JRuby (due to need for better Web Service Security support via Java).  One of the gems I use is [daemons](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) to create a background job.

The issue is that it use fork+exec to create the background process, but thats a no-no with JRuby.

So - is there an alternative gem/wrapper for creating background jobs?

My current thoughts are to just call rake from a shell script and let the rake task run forever...

Thanks in advance, Chris.

UPDATE
We are currently using a couple of Java threading related wrappers, namely https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler and https://github.com/philostler/acts_as_executor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cannot fork in JRuby you are basically left with having to refactor your daemon code so that the daemon can be executed as a standard foreground application then create a separate daemon launcher that will run and background the daemon. You can look at [spoon](https://github.com/headius/spoon) and also check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/448884) which uses spoon to create a more elaborate launcher. Also [jruby-jsvc](https://github.com/nicobrevin/jruby-jsvc) provides the glue to use [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) with a JRuby daemon.

Comment: Thanks - those look interesting.

Comment: I tried doing something with spoon, but in the end it wasn't worth the overhead of ruby (for speed), I just used a bash script and it seems to be working nicely so far.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in http://torquebox.org/ it includes scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative, called Spoon written by Charles Nutter. See his blog http://blog.headius.com/2009/05/fork-and-exec-on-jvm-jruby-to-rescue.html and the gist https://gist.github.com/321084 for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I created a gem for the easy creation of Ruby & JRuby daemons: [raad](https://github.com/praized/raad/) (Ruby as a daemon). It works identically with MRI Ruby or JRuby, simple, lightweight, transparent.