# Jruby and Forking

Tags: jvm, fork, jruby, jvm-arguments

Working for a large company, we are using the parallel_tests gem to run our cucumber automation.  This works well for our Ruby divisions, but for our Jruby folk we need another option.  The issue is that Jruby (as of 1.7) fork spawns a new java JVM without the JVM options.  I have figured out that I need 1 of 2 solutions and I'm not exactly sure how to implement either of them.

1. We need to be able to pass the JVM options into fork so we can get all the options we need.

or

2. We need to change how the gem handles forking so the processes all run on the same JVM

I don't know if either of these solutions are a possibility, but maybe someone else will know better

According to a solution posted at [Alternative for spawning a process with 'fork' in jRuby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818463/alternative-for-spawning-a-process-with-fork-in-jruby)

I found out the solution for this. We can use the built-in library FFI in JRuby to 'simulate' the Process.fork in MRI.

## To mimic the Process.fork in MRI Ruby

module JRubyProcess
  require 'ffi'
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Library::LIBC
  attach_function :fork, [], :int
end

pid = JRubyProcess.fork do
  #do_your_work
end
More details:

https://github.com/ffi/ffi

http://blog.headius.com/2008/10/ffi-for-ruby-now-available.html

another option was to use spoon:
https://github.com/headius/spoon

I am no linux guru, but these seem like simple ways to implement Jruby.  Does anyone know if this is an effective solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any safe way you can fork the jvm like you can ruby.  There is a gem called [childprocess](https://github.com/jarib/childprocess/) that provides cross platform process managemant.

I've created a gem called [jcukeforker](https://github.com/jesg/jcukeforker) that can run both features and scenarios in parrellel in jruby.

Feel free to submit an issue or a pull request for setting environment variables on the subprocesses.  This is only relevant if you want the subprocess to have different environment variables than the parent process.