# Jruby Daemon Frameworks

Tags: jruby

I am looking for a current daemon framework that is compatible with JRuby. I am trying to update a project that was using the [Raad](https://github.com/colinsurprenant/raad) gem, which is not currently Ruby 2.5 compatible.

I am aware that this question duplicates [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349629/ruby-daemons-and-jruby-alternative-options) but all of those answers seem to also be out of date.